# Update mysql table based on another table and file input

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of user name in a file like this:

```
userE
userZ
userA
...
```

I have two tables in mysql database

`Users` table:

```
| UID |  NAME |
|-----|-------|
| 101 | userQ |
| 102 | userZ |
| 103 | userA |
...
```

`Roles` table:

```
| UID | RID |
|-----|-----|
| 101 |  10 |
| 101 |  20 |
| 102 |  10 |
| 102 |  30 |
| 103 |  10 |
| 103 |  30 |
| 103 |  20 |
...
```

A list of user name from the file need to match with the user table to figure out the `uid` and that userid if exist for `rid=30` then that row need to be removed.

Let me know if this is still not clear.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Yes, I meant removing the row that contain rid:30 if  that uid listed in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to first load your names of users from a file to a temporary table (lets call it `delete_users`) with `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
CREATE TABLE delete_users (`name` varchar(32));

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/delete_users.txt' 
INTO TABLE delete_users
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or most likely '\r\n' if it's Windows
(@name)
SET name = TRIM(@name);
```

Then you use a query

```
DELETE r
  FROM roles r JOIN users u
    ON r.uid = u.uid JOIN delete_users d
    ON u.name = d.name
   AND r.rid = 30;
```

And finally drop `delete_users` table

```
DROP TABLE delete_users;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eee6/1)** demo

Comment: excellent!.. thanks a lot.  whats wrong with other folks who give down vote.

Comment: As far as downvotes are concerned usually they come from not showing what you've already tried to do (usually relevant parts of your code with explanation what you expect and what doesn't work) to solve the problem in your question. It's kind of in the StackOverflow rules. Sometimes when you don't have your code yet creating a sqlfiddle to help people who want to help you usually helps from being downvoted.

Comment: thanks. I am not a dba but trying to get few things done quickly where I couldn't find anything straight forward in online documents. you response has been very helpful not only for this question but also how I put my question in the future.